# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docutils' distribution was not found and is required by catkin-pkg

Tags: python, cmake, ros, catkin

I am installing ros kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and I get this error when I try `catkin_make`:

```
ibrahim@ibrahim-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
ibrahim@ibrahim-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws
ibrahim@ibrahim-Lenovo-ideapad-500-15ISK:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/build"
####
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (message):
  Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (catkin_find_pkg catkin
  /home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/src): Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_find_pkg", line 5, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
      @_call_aside
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
      f(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
      working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
      ws.require(__requires__)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
      needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
      raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)

  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docutils' distribution was not
  found and is required by catkin-pkg


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ibrahim/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
ibrahim@ibrahim-Lenovo-i
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the [docutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docutils/) package. Try

```
pip3 install docutils
```

If you get a permission denied, try adding `--user` after it (or sudo).

Comment: the command did not work it says "bash: pip3: command not found" 
 
so i tried sudo apt-get install docutils  but i got this Package docutils is a virtual package provided by:
  python3-docutils 0.12+dfsg-1
  python-docutils 0.12+dfsg-1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'docutils' has no installation candidate

Comment: then i tried sudo apt-get install docutils-* and i got this 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'docutils-writer-odt' for glob 'docutils-*'
Note, selecting 'docutils-common' for glob 'docutils-*'
Note, selecting 'docutils-doc' for glob 'docutils-*'
docutils-common is already the newest version (0.12+dfsg-1).
docutils-common set to manually installed.
docutils-doc is already the newest version (0.12+dfsg-1).
docutils-doc set to manually installed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded

Comment: You need to install python3 in order to get pip3. Try `sudo apt-get install python3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried

```
$ sudo pip install docutils
```

with the same issue, then try upgrading `setuptools` package:

```
$ sudo pip install -U setuptools
```